# Java connecting and executing statements to database without blocking the program

Tags: java, database, performance, connection

While im executing a connection or a new statement to a database, the program blocks until it recives the response from the database.

I tried, for example, showing some messages before executing the code that connects to the DB:

//Button that performs the action (JFrame Swing)

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

lblStat.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
lblStat.setText("Connecting...");
Thread.sleep(2000);


if (Connect(con, logger.textolog , tns, user, password)){
lblStat.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
lblStat.setText("Connected");
}

}
```

// Boolean method witch connects to the database

```
public boolean Connect(Connection con,JTextArea texto, String tns, String user, String password){
          try //try connection to database
           {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:"+tns+";user="+user+";password="+password);
                conexion=con;
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers("Connected with "+user+"@"+tns);
                setUser(user);
                setPassword(password);
                setTns(tns);
                return true;
                }
            catch (Exception i) {
                setChanged();
                notifyObservers("Exception:"+i.getMessage());
                return false;
               }
```

Following this example, I would expect that my LblStat turns first into "Connecting..." (at least for two seconds) and then execute the connection to the database, if the method returns true, then the lblStat would change it's text to "Connected".

This does not happen, the program blocks and just changes the text to "Connected" if the method results true.

This happens to any code I execute on the action before the Connection method (showing JOptionPanes or any kind of notification).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youre blocking the AWT-Thread and there's no-one left to show the yellow text. Use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for all operations taking any non-negligible time.